# Me sale Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected

Tags: php, mysql

He estado iniciando en este de la programación, y tengo un error que me sale cuando intento ejecutarlo me sale, no conozco muy bien sobre el tema.

Este es el que permitia la conexion DatabaseP.php

```
<?php 
class Database{
    private $server = "localhost";
    private $user = "root";
    private $pass = "";
    private $db = "tiendaelva";
    private $charset = "utf8";

    function conectar(){
        try{
            $conexion = "mysql:host" . $this->server . "; dbname=" . $this->db . ";
            charset=" . $this->charset;
            $options = [
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
            ];
            $pdo = new PDO($conexion, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);

            return $pdo;
            
        } catch(PDOException $e){
            echo 'Error conexion: ' . $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

?>

Este es Productos.php

```
<?php 
include "Config/DatabaseP.php";
$data = new Database();
$con = $data->conectar();

$sql = $con->prepare("SELECT ID, Producto, Precio FROM producto WHERE Activo=1");
$sql->execute();
$resultado = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

?>

Comment: Pon un igual aquí: `mysql:host` para que quede así: `mysql:host=` a ver si con eso lo arreglamos